# How can I load a Page using Codeigniter controller?

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, url-rewriting

I have made a kind of CMS using CodeIgniter. It loads the page content from Database depending on the `slug` text passed in the URL parameter like e.g. about, services, contact.

In the controller code, I have remapped the index method to take the slug as parameter to it as default index methods don't allow parameters. 
Check the code of my `page` controller on the link below :

http://pastebin.com/MwsVzRwQ

The way this works is, I have set `page` controller to load as default. So every time I open my site like this

http://www.mysite.com

it loads the controller like this

http://www.mysite.com/page

If we pass the slug to it, it loads the page content of that slug from database, like this

http://www.mysite.com/page/about
http://www.mysite.com/page/portfolio

If we don't pass the slug, it loads the home page.

Now what I want to do is, I don't want this 'page' text to appear in URL. So pages should open like this

http://www.mysite.com/about

http://www.mysite.com/portfolio

I guess this will be possible through URL rewriting. 
I have already done URL rewriting for removing `index.php` from URL which is normally done for all Codeigniter websites. Below is the code of my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|uploads|fckeditor|assets|robots\.txt)

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /jobsite/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Now the question is, how can I make the URL work like this

http://www.mysite.com/about

http://www.mysite.com/portfolio

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add this to your config/routes.php file:

```
$route[':any'] = 'your_controller';
```

Then in *your_controller*, you can access the URI segment with:

```
$this->uri->segment(1);
```

Once you have the URI segment, you can query the DB for it and send the data off to your view. If the URI segment is empty, load the home page.

Comment: gr8, that worked. how can I add exception for some controllers like /admin_panel, /order_manager etc.

Comment: @aslamdoctor from the CI documentation: "Routes will run in the order they are defined. Higher routes will always take precedence over lower ones."

If it worked, want to accept it as the correct answer? :)

Comment: of-course, it is accepted. but if you can help me out with this admin_panel thing, that will be appreciated :)

Comment: Just add something like:
`$route['admin_panel'] = 'admin_panel_controller';` BEFORE the :any line in my answer.


If you've got a small number of pages that should be handled by the same controller, you might want to replace :any with a simple regex:
`$route['about|contact|services'] = 'your_controller';`

Comment: gr8, it worked but now sub pages of admin_panel like "admin_panel/user_manager" and "admin_panel/pages_manager" are giving problem :(
sorry friend but I m really in need to get this resolved

Comment: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

In particular check out the `:num` and `:any` and regex parts - they'll do exactly what you need.

Comment: ok, I already looked at it but I will check again. 
thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so what I would do is what yRosen is proposing, with a little bit of differences and as mentionned in the correct order :

First your admin controller then everything else :

```
$route['admin_panel/user_manager/(:any)'] = "admin_panel/user_manager/$1";
$route['admin_panel/pages_manager/(:any)'] = "admin_panel/pages_manager/$1";
$route['admin_panel'] = "admin_panel";

$route['(:any)'] = "pages/$1";
```

Another thing i usually consider when making a complex site or playing too much with urls is put the admin on a separate host.
You reserve "www.myhost.com" for the public side, and use "admin.myhost.com" for the admin part. Of course then it need 2 CI installs and a little duplication of models but it can save time and have increase security.